# learning from independent points

Tags: correlation, statistical-significance, predictive-models, independence

Based on a previous [Question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/257818/independence-of-points-from-same-underlying-function/258060?noredirect=1#comment493841_258060), I want to ask what is the dependence structure of points from the same underlying function , which allows us predict a new point belonging to this same unknown function (also in some cases quantify the uncertainty).

Consider a set of input points $\textbf{X}^1=\{x_1^1,x_2^1,...,x_N^1\}$. Also consider any function $f(x)$, for example $$f(x)=sin(x)$$

Now assume we take $iid$ samples from $\textbf{X}^1$ denoted as $\textbf{X}=\{x_1,x_2,...,x_n\}$ and we find $\textbf{Y}=f(\textbf{X})=\{y_1,y_2,...,y_n\}$.
All samples from $\textbf{Y}$ are independent since I sampled randomly from $\textbf{X}^1$ , i.e. $P(y_i|y_j)=P(y_i)$ for $i,j \in \{1,2,..n\}$.

Assume all the inputs $\textbf{X}$ and responses $\textbf{Y}$ are similair to the graph below.
[image]

Many methods in literature will use the given points $\{\textbf{X},\textbf{Y}\}$ shown as black dots to find the value of $y_{new}$ at input $x_{new}$ shown as a red dot. Therefore, there is some kind of dependence between $\{x_i,y_i\}$ and $\{x_j,y_j\}$.

What is this dependence in structure, i.e how are $P(y_i|x_i)$ related to $P(y_j|x_j)$ ? In other words, what kind of commonalities do methods (regression, splines, kernel regression) that infer the underlying function ($sin(x)$) depend on.

Comment: How is this distinct from your earlier question [Independence of points from same underlying function](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/257818/independence-of-points-from-same-underlying-function)? The answer to both questions is that there's a distinction between conditional independence (what is assumed in the regression model) and unconditional independence (which couldn't teach you more than the unconditional distribution of Y).

Comment: If you can make this clearly distinct from that earlier question this might be able to reopen, but otherwise you should clarify your previous question than ask what seems to be a slightly differently expressed version of the same question.

Comment: @Glen_b This question is different from my last question. In the last question I want to infer where $y_i$'s are independent. In this question I want to understand how we can learn $y_new$ from independent points. Therefore, this question is building upon the last question and not a duplicate.

Comment: Your previous question asks "Isn't the fact that if samples are independent then they can't learn new information from each other?" while your new question says "independence means that you cannot use independent points to learn information about other points. Therefore, how can these functions learn the underlying function?". This is the same question.

Comment: @Glen_b You are correct. However, at the beginning of the previous question my goal was to ask whether $y_i$'s are independent. After the answer to that question I thought of posting a general question based on that I learned the fact that $y_i$'s are independent.

Comment: The questions are not sufficiently distinct as they stand. I said earlier: "*If you can make this clearly distinct from that earlier question this might be able to reopen*"; and that still holds. I'd suggest you make a substantial edit of this question, including a link to the previous question and a clarification of how you're not asking what your previous question does (at the moment they still seem to read as if they're essentially asking the same thing). The edit will place the question in the review queue and people  can then vote to reopen if they think the two are different.

Comment: @Glen_b I have adjusted this question. I do hope it can be reopened. Thank you